# can't find the configure() method in WebSecurityConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a SecurityConfig class that implements WebSecurityConfiguration.
The problem occurs when I try to call the super.configure() method, apparently it doesn't exist (it got deprecated??).

so what should i do in this case? with what function should I replace it.

Here is the SecurityConfig class :

```
package com.example.app.security;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;


@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfiguration {
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception  {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        super.configure(auth)
    }}

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        super.configure(httpSecurity);
    }
```

Comment: If you `@Override` it, you must be able to call `super.configure(...)`. So please, tell us the complete error you get.

Comment: Try extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` instead of `WebSecurityConfiguration`